# uploded image not saved in media folder

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [BASE_DIR / "static"]
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media/")
MEDIA_URL = '../media/images/'
```

urls.py

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    # Use static() to add url mapping to serve static files during development (only)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

models.py

```
    profile_image = models.ImageField(upload_to="../media/images")
```

file path:

```
-main_project
   /app             #django app
   /media/images    #media folder inside image folder
   /main            #django main app
   /static/css      #static folder for js,css,images,fonts
   /templates       #html templates
```

I have also tried other way but still, my image is not uploaded in media folder

Comment: Is your image is `showing` successfully in `Django Admin` through the uploaded image's `url` ?

Comment: Yes @Van image is showing successfully through Django Admin

Answer (score 1):

Change `MEDIA_URL` and `MEDIA_ROOT` to:

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media")
```

Once you define above you don't need to explicitly put media folder inside `ImageField`:

```
profile_image = models.ImageField(upload_to="images")
```

See the official **[docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/files/#managing-files)** about managing files

Comment: Hello, I have also tried this method but still not uploding

Comment: Make sure you have created `media` folder, and `DEBUG` is set to `True`

Answer (score 0):

firstly change to this

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media")
```

and in you model

```
profile_image = models.ImageField(upload_to="images")
```

and i guess you are using form to upload  the image so in that

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

use enctype and if still doesn't work for you try to update it from admin panel than tell me it update or not

Comment: it is working properly if I upload an image from the admin panel but if I tried to upload an image from the front end then it's not working.